# injecting @EJB from different module but same application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

I have an application on a Weblogic Server.
I have issues with injecting an EJB from my RESTWEBservice into my SOAPwebservice.
This application have several modules. Only Three of them is important now.

The deployment looks like this:

Application

- API (JAR)
- SOAPWebService (WAR)
- RESTWebService(WAR)

Both Webservices have the API built into them.
Here is the important part of the classes.
My RestWebservice EJB I want to inject:

```
@Local(EJBSOAPinterface.class)
@Stateless(mappedName = "RESTCLASS", name="RESTCLASS")
public class RESTCLASS implements EJBSOAPinterface{...}
```

The interface in the API which both modules use:

```
@Local
public interface EJBSOAPinterface{....}
```

The SOAP webserviceModule who wants to inject the EJB

```
public SOAPCLASS {
@EJB(lookup="JNDINAME..")
EJBSOAPinterface ejb;
......}
```

I have tried to use both @Local and @Remote on both interface and the EJB. it doesn't work.

I have tried this to inject the EJB as well

```
public SOAPCLASS{
@EJB(name="RESTCLASS")
EJBSOAPinterface ejb;
.....}
```

it doesn't work either.
The problem is that my SOAPCLASS wont deploy because of that injection.
I get different Exceptions depending on how I do it. But currently I get

> java.lang.InstantiationException: Error creating bean with name: "....."
> ..... Dependency injection failure: can't find the bean definition about class interface "....."

I am kind of new to java.

Comment: what jndi name did you use? During the startup there should be some output giving the available jndi names for `EJBSOAPinterface`, you should try them all.

Comment: i am checking the binding name on weblogic Server and using that one. its something like RESTCLASS#INTERFACEPACKETNAME.EJBSOAPinterface

Comment: There should be some other names including the .war name (and .ear if you have one)

Comment: I do get 2 more Binding names. From gradle for both the EJB class and interface class.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - SOLVED.
I did put @Remote instead of @Local on the interface. And the same thing on the EJB itself. The JNDI name i had was correct (RESTCLASS#INTERFACEPACKETNAME.EJBSOAPINTERFACE).

The problem was that when i deploy the application on the WLServer i deployed the SOAPCLASS Before the RESTCLASS. 
Which means that it couldnt find any JNDI name yet. Because it wasnt built yet.
I just changed the deploymentorder of those 2 and it worked instantly.
Thanks!